# Drupal 8:How to add tags for custom content types

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

Newbie here!

I go to Structure > Content types > Add content type and create a new content type.

But how can I add tags to my new content type, just like when you go to Content > Add content > Article, you get the option to enter a title, tags and body.

How can I add the capability to add tags to my new content type?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `/admin/structure/types` and press on <kbd>manage fields</kbd> of your custom content type

Press on the <kbd>+Add field</kbd> button, and use **Re-use an exiting field** (the drop down on the right) to select the existing `Entity Referenc: field_tags`

[image]

Then go to **manage form display**, for tags change the widget to `autocomplete (Tags style)`

**PS**: I suggest you install [admin toolbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar) if you haven't already.

Comment: It does not look like _tags_ field in articles

Comment: @wanna_be_superman then go to **manage form display** for tags change the widget to `autocomplete (Tags style)`

Comment: I love the **PS**.

Comment: can you tell me some necessary/useful modules  @No Sssweat

Comment: @wanna_be_superman **[meta tag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag)** for SEO, **[pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto)** to automatically give aliases to your nodes, **[Secure Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/securelogin)** for security. **[Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect)** so if you change url, your old url automatically redirects to your new url path (SEO) **[Re-Captcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha)** to prevent bots from registering to your site. Ummm... idk what else, it depends on what you're trying to build, really.

Comment: Are the prior 2 comments the newest workaround to ask questions about module recommendations? Comments cannot be put on hold, right?